# Escape or Ignore Postman Variables

Tags: postman

I'm trying to send the following (literal) text in a request body in Postman:

```
{
  "message": "Hi {{USERNAME}} your code is {{CODE}}"
}
```

However, in my Postman environment I have a USERNAME variable, so Postman is substituting in the variable value and the following hits my backend (note that I don't have a CODE variable in Postman):

```
{
  "message": "Hi username_value_in_postman your code is {{CODE}}"
}
```

So I'm looking for a way to escape or ignore the Postman variable syntax so that it sends the literal string. I've searched the docs and SO, but didn't find anything useful for my problem, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escaping doesn't seem to work, so I guess you'd either need to rename your variable(s) or use Pre-request and Tests scripts:

In Pre-resuqest script, you can write this code:

```js
pm.variables.set('usernameBackup', pm.variables.get('USERNAME'));
pm.environment.unset('USERNAME');
```

And you set the environment variable again in the Tests script:

```js
pm.environment.set('USERNAME', pm.variables.get('usernameBackup'));
pm.variables.unset('usernameBackup');
```

Comment: This works perfectly for the specific question asked and for my local testing use case it is ideal, thank you. Annoyingly, when I hit the actual backend, the {{USERNAME}} variable is being used for authentication in Postman, so this solution will break my auth. I will just have to suck it up and rename my vars in the longer term. Thanks again

Comment: Can't edit the comment above, but scrap my last statement. You can of course use pre request scripts to manually build the auth header too which saves some tedious renaming for the sake of 1 request.

Comment: This is ridiculous. Do I really have to rename the variable before sending its literal name on a string because Postman doesn't have any native way to avoid that? Absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: @RenanLazarotto: I played with this a bit and didn't find any other way. Perhaps it has been resolved since. It'd be nice if escaping worked, but on the other hand this is not a common use case, so it's probably not a top priority for the Postman team.

Comment: @pavelsaman Seems to be the case. I was annoyed because I like the double-braces syntax and didn't want to change it. I gave up and decided to use another syntax, its just easier.